# Real time code compiling?

Tags: java, eclipse

I was watching the livestream at http://www.humblebundle.com, and I saw them running the application, AND making changes to the code in Eclipse. Is this just changes for the next time they compile and run, or was he actually changing the application as it was running somehow?

Comment: You should include more context in your question so it makes sense after the livestream ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes.
In Debug mode, eclipse can compile and change class files in a running JVM, this is called **Hot Code Replace**.

> The idea is that you can start a debugging session on a given runtime
>   workbench and change a Java file in your development workbench, and
>   the debugger will replace the code in the receiving VM while it is
>   running. No restart is required, hence the reference to "hot".

Source: [Eclipse Wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_hot_code_replace?)

There are certain circumstances where this won't work, in which case Eclipse will prompt you to restart.
[image: Hot code replace failed]

Comment: The "certain circumstances" are those when you're editing something more than just a method body, i.e. adding a new method, changing signature, a new class or configurations. So basically hot code replace is very very limited in what it can do

Answer (score 1):

This is called [**hot code replace**](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_hot_code_replace?):

> The idea is that you can start a debugging session on a given runtime workbench and change a Java file in your development workbench, and **the debugger will replace the code in the receiving VM while it is running**. No restart is required, hence the reference to "hot".

Answer (score 1):

It's not really possible to tell from the stream. Java's capable of both to some extent - you can, with some restrictions, replace classes loaded by a JVM using the debugger. There's also [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/), which gets rid of a great deal of those restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Ability to change application code while running is the feature of debugger. In Eclipse and many other popular IDEs it works "out of the box". Feature has several restrictions: can't change method signatures, add/remove class members, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in debug mode you can make certain changes while the application is running.  Whether or not it is valid varies based on if the change is to currently loaded code.  For example, you could change a sort function while the program isn't sorting and it will use the new code the next time it sorts.