# How Class loading takes place when we modify some object in eclipse debug mode

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, classloader

while debugging some program in eclipse we can modify value/reference of some variable/object, after that does eclipse reload that class, if yes how?? or basically how does eclipse internally handles such things??

i googled it but couldn't find any related result. any sort of reference is welcomed..

Comment: "Hot code replace" ? For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335239/real-time-code-compiling

Answer (score 1):

I think Eclipse just changes the memory. That is, it doesn't reload the class, but *changes* it's .class representation.